# How can I have just only icons of apps in tasklist in Awesome wm ver 3.5?

Tags: lua, awesome-wm

In Awesome <3.5 I did it that way:

```
mytasklist[s] = awful.widget.tasklist(function(c)
  local task = { awful.widget.tasklist.label.currenttags(c, s) }
  return '', task[2], task[3], task[4]
end, mytasklist.buttons)
```

But in 3.5 that doesn't work anymore as in 3.5 there is no such function - awful.widget.tasklist.label.currenttags() and new function awful.widget.tasklist.filter.currenttags() returns just true or false so its not the real replacement.

Comment: So, no way to do it? (

Comment: @user112683,Andrey You mean Remove icons by putting the code put in the question in rc.lua ?

Answer (score -1):

You mean Remove icons by putting the code in the question in the rc.lua file ?

As of v3.5.1, tasklist icons can be removed by adding

```
theme.tasklist_disable_icon = true
```

to your theme.lua.

Docs: https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/classes/awful.widget.tasklist.html#beautiful.tasklist_disable_icon

Comment: OP wants only the icons, not to remove them.